# Test cases for Binary Search Tree (BST) remove function using linked lists C++

Tags: c++, testing, methods, binary-search-tree, implementation

**Question:** What test cases should I use to test the remove function?

*My Thoughts:*

case 1: delete when no element is in the system.

case 2: delete when there is only one element in the system.

case 3: delete when the left side of the tree is empty.

case 4: delete when the right side of the tree is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, third, and fourth test cases are fine. You should also cover the case where both left and right children are present and both are not present but there is more than one element. This will remove the need for your second test case.

What you should look out for is the way you reorder your tree when you have deleted an item. It should continue to follow whatever order your tree is structured to be in.

I'm not sure what you mean by "using linked lists"?

Comment: Yes, your idea is interesting, I am going to try that. Also, for other people's future reference linked lists refer to using the idea of nodes and traverse to go from one node to another. Some times they have advantages comparing to arrays.